# Allow @ character in pattern

Tags: regex

What do I need to add to this:

```
 ^((sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49\w+(,|$)|(sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(?!E)\w+(,|$))+$
```

So that

```
+E1234498912345678@destinazione1.italtel.it,tel: +498912345678,sip: +E123449D1238912345678@destinazione1.italtel.it,sip: +E1234498912345678@origine1.italtel.it
```

Is valid?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Define `valid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow not only `@` but also the dots `.` . So replace `\w+` with `[@\w.]+`.

```
^((sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49[@\w.]+(,|$)|(sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(?!E)[@\w.]+(,|$))+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hJ7nT4/6)